# Find which app service an error occurred on in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm running a simple query in Azure Application Insights:

```
exceptions 
| where type == "Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException"
```

(the exact details of the exception are not relevant here, it could be any exception).

Say my site/services consist of numerous App Services and other Azure resources, is there some way to indicate in the query results which App Service the error originated from?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is inspecting the value of the `cloud_RoleName` field. It is populated with resource name, for example the app service name. This works for most resources. `cloud_RoleInstance` can also help in identifying the azure resource.

If those fields are not populated out-of-the-box for a workload you can [set them using code if needed using the AI SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - for me, I see an ID of some sort there - 14 characters, mixture of letters and numbers - but I can't see how this relates to my other App Services?

Comment: Have you deployed containers to your web app?

Comment: Hi @peter Bons, no.

Comment: This ID of some sort, it that the value of cloud_RoleName or cloud_RoleInstance ?